# How to catch some specific rows and SUM values in them?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table:

```
ID   SubID   Cost

 1    NULL     10
 2    NULL     10
 3      3a     10
 3a   NULL     10
 4    NULL     10
 ...
```

I need to to catch all rows with SubID and SUM Costs (in this example Cost 3 with Cost 3a).
So, I need to return it like:

```
ID   SubID   Cost

 1    NULL     10
 2    NULL     10
 3      3a     20
 4    NULL     10
 ...
```

Seems like I have to join this table on it self (ON ID = SubID), but I can't get it working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a maximum of one child per parent, and nested only one deep, this will work:

```
SELECT parent.ID, parent.SubID, parent.Cost + COALESCE(child.Cost, 0)
FROM someTable parent
LEFT JOIN someTable child
  ON parent.SubID = child.ID
WHERE parent.ID NOT IN (SELECT SubID from someTable WHERE SubID IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: That doesn't return anything at all.  I think the `WHERE` clause needs to be `WHERE parent.ID NOT IN (SELECT SubID from #MyTable WHERE SubID IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: I just find out that some rows have more than one child per parent. What should I do in that case? Thank you!

Comment: If they have more than one child, where are those children referenced - you only have 1 SubID column?

Comment: Looks like this: 3 - 3a - 10, 3a - 3b - 10, 3b - NULL - 10

Comment: Unfortunately, a nested model can only be retrieved by either making a fixed number of joins (for instance, if you never have more than 3 children you can use 3 joins) or by using a loop with procedural code.  You could also build a dynamic query to join as many times as needed, however a large number of joins will have a noticeable performance hit.  I would strongly recommend against using such a model where you need to crawl the entire tree at any one time, as you would in this case to get a total.